# using replaceWith in jquery input textbox to select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery code. My problem is that I want to replace the textbox `input` with a `select` dropdown using jQuery. Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var select  = $("<select>").addClass("form-group");

    var request = {
        'action': 'zipcode'
    };

    $.getJSON(zibbra.getAjaxUrl(), request, function(response) {
        var error = $("<select>")
        $.each(response, function(i, field){
            $('#billing_zipcode').append($('<option>', {
                value: field.id,
                text: field.zipcode
            }));
        });
        $("#billing_zipcode").replaceWith(dropdown);
    });
});
```

```html
<input id="billing_zipcode" name="billing[zipcode]" value="" type="text">
```

It seems it's not working. Can someone help me figured this thing out? Any help is muchly appreciated. TIA

Comment: You're trying to append `option` elements to an `input` which is never going to work. You need to replace the `input` with a `select` first, then append the options to it

Comment: how will i able to do that ? i really need to override the input textbox only  cause its a plugin from wp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to create select element and you forget to append options into it

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var select  = $("<select>").addClass("form-group");

    var request = {
        'action': 'zipcode'
    };

    $.getJSON(zibbra.getAjaxUrl(), request, function(response) {
        var dropdown = $("<select>");
        $.each(response, function(i, field){
            dropdown.append($('<option>', {
                value: field.id,
                text: field.zipcode
            }));
        });
        $("#billing_zipcode").replaceWith(dropdown);
    });
});
```

Comment: no error its just prints it like this 
<input id="billing_zipcode" name="billing[zipcode]" value="" type="text">
<option value="79">1000</option>
<option value="81">7000</option>
<option value="85">2344</option>
<option value="89">1250</option>
<option value="90">2000</option>
<option value="91">55666</option>
</input>